# What's the max speed of EOSIO contract?

Tags: smart-contract

I try to do performance testing about EOS contract. I built private EOS network with 6 nodes.
I use apache bench to formulate http requests, and post to EOS service `http://127.0.0.1:8888/v1/chain/abi_json_to_bin`

The test result is, if the apache bench concurrent=1, per-request costs 3ms; and if the apache bench concurrent=2, per-request cost 6ms。

It seems that the max speed of EOS is 300tps/s。I don't know whether i need to optimize EOS config.ini? I need almost 10000tps/s, and how can i get this target?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `/v1/chain/abi_json_to_bin` to serialize your action arguments. Once you fetch ABI from nodeos by `/v1/chain/get_abi`, there are many libraries that allow you for serializing arguments by yourself in local. If you often send same type actions (for example, eosio.token::transfer), they can utilize same ABI you downloaded.

Benchmark result can vary depending on environment setup. nodeos has configurable options for the number of threads handling requests, and wasm-runtime (eos-vm-jit and enable-eos-vm-oc will bring you fastest result) also affects how long a transaction consumes to be executed.

Comment: thanks very much!!! Recently, we optimize the params and test other functions on local cluster of six nodes, and other function can get performance of 10000tps. 
Lucky, your answer prove our test results, and we will optimize the params you suggested, thanks again!

Comment: he problem of abi_json_to_bin has been improved, and we have also done offline signatures by the way, but the overall tps from getting the chain and block to the final push transaction is about 200/sec. Our own contract method only push transaction qps is 540/sec, and eos' own transfer contract method is 1300/sec, which is far from reaching our desired goal. What is the bottleneck of push transaction for eos single chain? Have we improved by changing the configuration file or using a higher version?
Thanks a lot!